# HTML and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi how will I reduce the distance of the two dropdowns between each other?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
        <p class="col-md-offset-1"><b>Type of Meal:</b></p>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <%--                                options --%>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <%--                                options --%>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try changing `class="col-md-offset-1"` `class="form-group col-md-2"` `class="col-md-8"` to 1-8

Comment: Google didn't return enough information on this subject? Google how to reduce the space between bootstrap columns. Try *something* before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Starfleet officer</p>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <select class="form-control form-group">
            <option>Spock</option>
            <option>Kirk</option>
          </select>

          <select class="form-control form-group">
            <option>Picard</option>
            <option>Riker</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that Bootstrap uses 12 columns to a row.